# Cannot decrypt given cyphertext twice with same AES Object

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, aes, pycryptodome

I am using an AES object (aesDecryptObj ) to decrypt a cyphertext that was encrypted using a seperate AES object (aesEncryptObj ).

```py
def aesInit():
    global aesEncryptObj
    global aesDecryptObj
    aesKey = <my key>
    aesEncryptObj = AES.new(aesKey, AES.MODE_CBC, iv=<My Init Vector>)
    aesDecryptObj = AES.new(aesKey, AES.MODE_CBC, iv=<My Init Vector>)

def aesEncrypt(clearStr):
    global aesEncryptObj 
    padded_data = pad(str(clearStr).encode("utf-8"), aesEncryptObj.block_size)
    e = aesEncryptObj.encrypt(padded_data)
    eb64 = base64.b64encode(e)
    d = eb64.decode('ascii')
    return(d)

def aesDecrypt(encryptedStr):
    global aesDecryptObj
    e = base64.b64decode(encryptedStr)
    b = aesDecryptObj.decrypt(e)
    b = unpad(b, aesDecryptObj.block_size)
    clearStr = b.decode('utf-8')
    return(clearStr)

aesInit()

cypherText = aesEncrypt('test') #this line will render the same result no matter how many times it is repeated

print(aesDecrypt(cypherText)) #this line executes fine
print(aesDecrypt(cypherText)) #this line throws the "padding is incorrect" error
```

Using aesEncryptObj sequentially any number of times produces successful results, however, when I use aesDecryptObj to decrypt a given cyphertext two or more times in a row I receive the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/Cryptodome/Util/Padding.py", line 90, in unpad
    raise ValueError("Padding is incorrect.")
ValueError: Padding is incorrect.
```

Should it be the case that, given the same ciphertext, aesDecryptObj would produce the same results as it did the first time it decrypted the value?

Comment: You gave these variables proper names in the code, why are you referring to them as "obj1" and "obj2" in the question? And where are they created, and what class are they?

Comment: Made changes per your comment. Hope it is more clear now. @Blorgbeard

Comment: You still have some remnants: "...Using obj2 sequentially..." Please fix these everywhere in your question.

Comment: What do you mean by "sequentially any number of times"? Do you mean encrypt the output of the previous encryption operation? Show this in your code too, don't make us guess.

Comment: Good job improving your question and congratulations on getting an answer, welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES objects have a state (at least with `AES.MODE_CBC`). You initialize that state with `iv=<My Init Vector>`. As you decrypt ciphertext the state changes. You need to reinitialize your object before you call decrypt again.

You probably want something like:

```
def aesDecrypt(encryptedStr):
    aesKey = <my key>
    aesDecryptObj = AES.new(aesKey, AES.MODE_CBC, iv=<My Init Vector>)
    e = base64.b64decode(encryptedStr)
    b = aesDecryptObj.decrypt(e)
    b = unpad(b, aesDecryptObj.block_size)
    clearStr = b.decode('utf-8')
    return(clearStr)
```

Or you can simply call `aesInit()` again after decrypting the first ciphertext.

Comment: Thank you, @kichik. That fixed it.

Comment: What do these states represent? How does the state prior to the first call to aesDecrypt(cypherText) differ from the state after the call?

Comment: That's the CBC (Cipher Block Chaining) state. Each block is XOR'ed with the ciphertext of the previous block and then encrypted. So the state has to remember the last block. For the first block, the "last" ciphertext is the IV.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response.